# Incompatible data types(hypersql)

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb, jdbc-odbc

Why should I get incompatible data types error?

```
int blockSize = 100;
String city="London";
" select * from"+
"(" +
" select l.* from lottotable as l where l.city='"+city+"' and  l.date< cast('"+date+"' as date) order by l.date desc " +
")" +
" order by date asc limit CONVERT("+blockSize+", SQL_INTEGER )"
```

Error is:

> `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException`: incompatible data type in operation: ; in LIMIT, OFFSET or FETCH in statement [ select * from( select l.* from lottotable as l where l.city='London' and  l.date< cast('2018-9-21' as date) order by l.date desc ) order by date asc limit CONVERT(100, SQL_INTEGER )]

Derby shut down normally

update:
the table structure is very simple
LOTTOTABLE(DATE,CITY,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5) ;
p1 to p5 are integers, date is of type date  and city is varchar

Comment: Not very familiar with java (I came here because this was originally tagged "MySQL"), but I would imagine posting your table structure might help.

Comment: Why `limit CONVERT(100, SQL_INTEGER )` instead of just `limit 100` ...?

Comment: limit CONVERT("+blockSize+", SQL_INTEGER )", blockSize is a variable being passed, check the code first then the error...

Comment: I'm asking why you think you need the CONVERT function at all.

Answer (score 1):

Change the query as suggested in the comments:

```
int blockSize = 100;
String city="London";
String queryText =
    " select * from"+
    "(" +
    " select l.* from lottotable as l where l.city='"+city+"' and  l.date< cast('"+date+"' as date) order by l.date desc " +
    ")" +
    " order by date asc limit "+blockSize;
```